# dynamically update php session variable created with ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to create a webpage that is 100% dynamic that can connect into any database without extra input.

Right now I am having some issues with a session variable I am passing from my a php page my ajax is calling.

This is the last thing my getfields.php page does

```
//Code to get information from database

//Loop to populate $column_array

$_SESSION['columnarray']=$column_array;
```

Then in my main page I use

```
$(document).on('click', '#submit-button', function(e){
    <?php
        $column_array = $_SESSION['columnarray'];
    ?>
    var arrayFromPHP = <?php echo json_encode($column_array);?>;
    $.each(arrayFromPHP, function (i, elem){
    if($('#checkbox'+elem).prop('checked'))
    {
        alert(elem)
    }
});
```

So that when I click submit it alerts me to which checkboxes were chosen. The whole point of what I'm trying to do is not have to hardcode any variables from the database at all.

I have 4 buttons each for a different table in my database on my page which dynamically loads checkboxes specific to the table selected. The getfields.php run every time a different table is selected which successfully updates the main page.

When I click the submit button it will alert me for all the checkboxes I have selected but if I change the table selected and click the submit button then nothing happens.  I have to reselect the first table I originally selected to have the alerts come through successfully.

I have 4 different $(document).on functions.  One for each different table until I get around to making that all work in one function.

I did try the following to try and catch all 4 different submit buttons at once

```
$(document).on('click', $('.submit-table'), function()....
```

But that alerted me every time I clicked anywhere on the page and still only worked for the first table selected.

Comment: Javascript runs on the client, PHP on the server. When you send your Javascript function to the client PHP inserts the values it has _at that time_. Any subsequent changes on the server won't reach the client unless you specifically request them with an AJAX call. Your code won't work as it stands.

Comment: Instead of using session variables, would it be worth creating one table, with one row, with the relevant variables stored? In that way, even after a disconnect, you would be able to retrieve the prior "state"?